# Awk vrs SQL for large dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, awk

I haven't worked with a group in my company since a merger and on our side we are strictly MSSQL with a little mysql but I'm finding out that  the new group is using a windows variant Awk to manage a few hundred million record DB.

When I say manage I mean routine monthly updates from data feeds, suppressing bad data, updating records based on logic results, and day to day query counts.  I am finding little comparative info on the web between the two but have run some cases where AWK was more efficient on data manipulation but not sure on what data set sizes.

I would have to think flat out query pulls on an indexed DB would be more efficient.  I'm at a point where I have to prove why SQL would be "better" but I honestly don't know enough about awk, since I've never used it.  So is it unheard of?  Are there benefits to AWK I'm not seeing?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  If the group has skill sets in awk but not SQL, they are going to write a better system in awk (alas).  Besides, flat file processing is becoming more popular these days.

Comment: I understand the :aint broke don;t fix it" mentality but the goal is also to do it the "best" and "most efficient"  their are skills sets on both sides of the table, just want to understand is if the way it is now is the best

Comment: There is no definitive answer here. It is going to boil down mostly to opinion and as such is considered off topic for SO.

Comment: Not seeking a definitive answer, but forum knowledge if feasibility for the application usage,

Comment: design of `awk` at one point had an aggressive goal of being a db query language but later that was dropped.  It's very good for text manipulation but doubt it can replace sql except for trivial cases.